# Why is that not lazy

Tags: haskell, ghc

I'm still starting to explore Haskell. I know this code "runs" in the `IO` monad. When it goes from the `l <- ...` line to the next one, the `IO - bind` is called.

One could think that because Haskell is **lazy**, the `l` is never evaluated. But "`bind`" always evaluates the previous command, is that right? Because the program produces the "file-not-found" error.

```
main = do
    l <- mapM readFile [ "/tmp/notfound" ]
    return ()
```

Comment: `l is never evaluated` -- Hm?  Lazy doesn't mean "never," it means "not yet" or "only when it is actually needed."

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes, but for the non-Haskellers, looking at the source code, `l` is not used anymore. But it's used implicitly, right?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> One could think that because Haskell is lazy, the l is never evaluated.

Yes, and it never is evaluated. However, due to the definition of `(>>=)` in `IO`, the action `readFile "/tmp/notfound"` is executed, and that means the runtime tries to open the file. If there is no such file, a "File not found" error is raised. If there were such a file, it would be opened, but its contents would not be read until demanded. In the above, they are not demanded, so the contents will not be read.

What *is* evaluated here (and even executed) is the action producing `l`. Since the file doesn't exist, that raises an error.

Answer (score 9):

If you expand the `do` notation in your code, you get:

```
main = (mapM readFile ["/tmp/notfound"]) >>= (\l -> return ())
```

So yes, `l` is never evaluated, but that doesn't mean that the call to `mapM` is never evaluated. `>>=` always needs to evaluate its left operand in order to produce a value at least to some degree (at least in the IO monad and in any other monad that comes to mind).